# Devise custom redirect_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to set up Devise such that any failed auth redirects to the sign up page, with the exception of the sign in page which will redirect to itself.  I have the following custom failure class:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    new_user_registration_path
  end

  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end
end
```

The trouble with that is that even a failed post to sign in redirects to sign up.  How can I detect within the `redirect_url` function which page the request came from so that I can redirect accordingly?

Comment: `request.referer` should give you the url from where the request came from. `URI(request.referer).path` if you just need the relative url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
redirect_path = "whareveeeeeeer.com"
redirect_to redirect_path
```

I use it in my DELETE method:

```
# DELETE /resource/sign_out
def destroy
    redirect_path = after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name)
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_out && is_flashing_format?
    yield resource if block_given?

    # We actually need to hardcode this as Rails default responder doesn't
    # support returning empty response on GET request
    respond_to do |format|
        format.all { head :no_content }
        format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to redirect_path }
    end 
end
```